# return a class name from method to cast with it

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I'm using FindControl to find a dynamic control, which works, but I can't get the type to cast it to.

First of all this code won't even compile like this because on my return statements in the ReturnCastType method it says "Class name is not valid at this point".

I've tried the method return keyword Type, dynamic, Object, and Control and can't get it to accept what I'm trying to do here.

```
foreach (var component in controls)
{
        if (component.Section == "Plan")
        {
            string controlName = GetPrefixAndId(component); 
            var castType = ReturnCastType(component);    
            var control = planPanel.FindControl(controlName) as castType; //i want to specify type to cast here

        }
}


private static dynamic ReturnCastType(CustomExamComponent component)
        {
            if (component.ComponentType == "Textbox")
            {
                return TextBox;
            }
            if (component.ComponentType == "Dropdown")
            {
                return DropDownList;
            }
            if (component.ComponentType == "Checkbox")
            {
                return CheckBox;
            }
            return null;
        }
```

Comment: What you're planning to do with `control` variable. Give one example?

Comment: `string controltext = control.Text;` if it returns TextBox for example. I'm just going to pull different properties from different  controls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you need something resolve dynamically at runtime,compile time types can't help you. Fortunately `Dynamic` is there for rescue.

```
foreach (var component in controls)
{
    if (component.Section == "Plan")
    {
        string controlName = GetPrefixAndId(component); 
        dynamic control = planPanel.FindControl(controlName);//Note the dynamic keyword
        string controltext = control.Text;//Will be resolved dynamically
    }
}
```

One caveat is that this code can fail at runtime if the properties/methods you try to use doesn't exist in the dynamic member. Otherwise, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you return `dynamic` from `ReturnCastType` (and what do you think it should be)? Simply return a Type like this:

```
private static Type ReturnCastType(CustomExamComponent component)
        {
            if (component.ComponentType == "Textbox")
            {
                return typeof(TextBox);
            }
            if (component.ComponentType == "Dropdown")
            {
                return typeof(DropDownList);
            }
            if (component.ComponentType == "Checkbox")
            {
                return typeof(CheckBox);
            }

            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }
```

Oh, and you shouldn't return a null here if you don't check for it in the calling method. Instead, you should fail immediately.